# Copy a shell script into multiple destination directories and run it

Tags: shell-script, shell, cp

I have multiple directories and sub-directories like C201201A/RA/, C201202A/RB etc. So I want to copy setphase.sh into all sub-directories and also run it. I have tried the below code

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -d */*/ > folders.txt
no=1
while read folder
    do echo $folder
       cp setphase.sh $folder
       sh setphase.sh
       no=`expr $no + 1`
done < folders.txt
```

where I have to write `sh setphase.sh`?

Comment: Do you really need to have the script in all of these subdirectories? Or is it sufficient just to be in each directory in turn when the script is run? (This would be far more usual. We don't copy `ls` into a directory before running it there.)

Comment: @roaima - yep.  if that's the case then something like `find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -execdir /path/to/setphase.sh {} \;` will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

If the script doesn't actually need to be in the directory (very few do...and those that do are almost certainly badly written and need to be fixed), you could use `find`'s `-execdir` option to just run the script inside each directory.  For example:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -execdir /path/to/setphase.sh \;
```

From the GNU `find` man page:

> `-execdir command ;`
>
> `-execdir command {} +`
>
> Like `-exec`, but the specified command is run from the  subdirectory  containing  the  matched  file,  which is not normally the directory in which you started `find`.
>
> This a much more secure method for invoking commands, as it avoids race conditions during resolution of the paths to the matched files.
>
> As  with  the `-exec` action, the `+` form of `-execdir` will build a command line to process more than one matched file, but any given  invocation of command will only list files that exist in the same subdirectory.
>
> If you use this option, you must ensure that your `$PATH` environment  variable does not reference `.`;  otherwise, an attacker can run any commands they like by leaving an appropriately-named file in a directory in which you will run `-execdir`.
>
> The same applies to having entries in $PATH which are  empty  or which  are  not  absolute  directory  names.   If any invocation returns a non-zero value as exit status,  then `find`  returns  a non-zero  exit  status.   If `find` encounters an error, this can sometimes cause an immediate exit, so some pending commands  may not  be  run at all.
>
> The result of the action depends on whether the `+` or the `;` variant is being  used; `-execdir command {} +` always returns true,  while `-execdir command {} ;` returns true only if command returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

If all the subdirectory are under `C2012A/` directory, you can `cp` the script to the subdirectories and run it afterwards using a `for` construct like:

```
for d in C2012A/*/; do
    cp setphase.sh "$d"
    sh "$d"/setphase.sh
done
```

Assuming the script does not depend on the location from where it is being run.

Also note that, by doing `sh setphase.sh`, you are explicitly mentioning to run the script as an argument to `sh` (may be `dash`, `bash` or other depending on your system) irrespective of the shebang, which may get you undesirable results if you use any bash-isms inside the script.

---

If the subdirectories are under different directories:

```
for d in C2012A/*/ A1812A/*/ B8012B/*/; do
    cp setphase.sh "$d"
    sh "$d"/setphase.sh
done
```

replace the directory names to meet your requirements.

Comment: My mistake. Subdirectoriey are present in different directories.

Comment: @Preet Check my edits..

Comment: Adding this line after copy the script. This works well.                                                                                            
     `( cd $d && sh setphase.sh )`

Comment: @Preet the script  should work as is in my answer..where is it failing?